# Emberjs - Ember conditionals break Jquery. Need simple fix

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

Handlebar conditionals actually delete the DOM elements inside of the conditionals, JQuery thinks that the newly generated DOM elements, despite their matching ID or class is something entirely different.

**I need a simple solution for this.** A solution that I can wrap my solutions in once per page. I don't want to have to tack .observes() after everything as that seems like a shoddy work-around

Right now I put my Jquery in the didInsertElement{} in my current view that is being used.

Simple Example:

exampleView -

```
didInsertElement {
  $('#exampleButton').on('click', function() {
    console.log('To Ember. Or to Angular. That is the question.')
  }
}
```

example.hbs -

```
{{#if booleanTrue}}
  <button id="exampleButton">Button go!</button>
{{/if}}
```

Comment: It's not Ember that removing DOM elements. Handlebars does it. Can you provide more specific code which refers to your problem?

Comment: **  Edited to include example & reworded question with less tone

Comment: I think u have an architecture problem. Maybe a single big view with a lot of HTML/Handlebars code and jQuery? Try to write your jQuery code as generic as possible, and split it up to components. Only use jQuery inside a component whenever possible. Then a `{{#if}}` arround the component will *not* break your code, since the components `didInsertElement` will be called on the rerender cycle. Extend handlebars with components and helpers for your need.

Comment: I usually place all of my JQuery in a didInsertElement in Object's generic view. I am doing this incorrectly then. I have never used a component. So they are basically single functions in the form of a js file, and then all of the separate component.js files are placed in a folder called component which is located in the scripts folder?

Comment: U should definitly use a build system! Then u probably have a folder scripts with a subfolder components for the JS code, and a folder templates with a subfolder components for the handlebars files! [Look here for components](http://emberjs.com/guides/components/). Checkout grunt, ember app kit, as possible build systems, but u can use any build system u want!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That approach is not best for Ember. For the future release of Ember they are planing to remove jQuery dependency. With Ember you don't have to use jQuery.

rewrite your code like this:

```
didInsertElement: function(){
  this.$().hide().fadeIn('slow'); // or any animation that you want
},
actions: {
  myButtonAction: function(){
    //do something
  }
}

{{#if booleanTrue}}
  <button id="exampleButton" {{action "myButtonAction"}}>Button go!</button>
{{/if}}
```

willDestroyElement is not right hook for animation. So you have to trigger it yourself.
I use my custom action like

```
actions: {
  deleteClicked: function(){
    var self = this;
    this.$().animate({ height: 'toggle' }, 300, function() {
      self.set('booleanTrue', false);
    });
  }
}
```

due to your comment I changed my answer

Comment: I **want** to use Jquery. Jquery is frankly way more fleshed out and provides wayyyyy more versatility than Handlebars use. What if I wanted multiple actions and the booleanTrue to toggle with a slide animation? How do they expect us to use these handlebars in place of Jquery when they haven't even created an {{else if}} conditional yet? I tried using conditionals for a hover function and it was a nightmare. If I moved the mouse quickly, the handlebars didn't even detect that I mouseLeave'd the hovered item.

Comment: Its true that u shouldnt use jQuery if u just need clicks, and else if is nothing more then a if inside the else, but thats not the point. there are definitly situations when u *have to* use jQuery or manuel DOM manipulation. But are u sure u have to use handlebars `if` *and* jQuery at the same point? It is *good* that the DOM is removed due performance reasons, but if u dont want, use bindAttr and a class to hide it just with CSS.

Comment: Handlebars is abstracted from application logic. It is not like underscore. That force you to write more testable code. You should never implement any logic in your templates

Comment: @saygun Could you give me an example of what you mean when you say that logic should never be implemented in my templates?

Comment: Here is example: <% for(i = 0; i < 6; i++) { %>
     <% if(cal.stop_cycling == true) break; %>
       <div class="cal-row-fluid cal-before-eventlist">
   <div class="cal-cell1 cal-cell" data-cal-row="-day1"><%= cal._day(i, day++) %></div>
  </div>
 <% } %>

It iterates and cal.stop_cycling should not be here. That if state belongs to your logic and should be in your template

Comment: @Krutius Speed is important for this project, but I also never use jquery to deal with dynamic dom elements, and I figured that using less than 50 lines of simple Jquery per page would not damage the performance of the software, which primarily deals with large amounts of data

Comment: @IanSteffy jQuery hat not a real relation to performance problems. My point was, that when the DOM parts covered by a false if condition are removed, the browser has less DOM to handle which increase the performance.

Comment: @saygun I used <% %> that for past Ruby on Rails projects but not for this one. Generally all of my jquery logic goes into the main view.